# Is Navagraha Stotra (Japakusuma-sankasham...) an independent work of Maharshi Vyasa or part of any scriptures?

Tags: vyasa, stotra

The Navagraha Stotra is said to have written by Maharshi Vyasa.  The Stotra link is given below:

[Navagrahastotra (with meanings)](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_navagraha/navanew.html?lang=sa)

Is it part of any scripture or just an independent work?

Comment: Yes, it's an independent work.